# GTA V Missions (issue?)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

so I finished the final heist, killed Devin Western and stuff. So now what do I do?

It says I'm 75% through the game but I've played several hours more and no missions... Trevor's mum has appeared and I got the meds for her and finished it and that's all that has happened since the final mission... What now, what about the last 25% to go?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Rockstar social club, for a list of thing you need for 100% completion.
Things required for 100% completion, have a colored line on the left, except the random events, which you just need to complete any 14 of them.

[image: Rockstar social club]

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so that will involve getting all the space ship parts and stuff?

Comment: @user117852 Yes mostly. You need to do half of the stunt stuff. But you don't need to collect submarine parts and nuclear waste. On the bottom there is a map for the location for spaceship parts and letter scraps.